# Removing first and last linebreaks

Tags: excel, vba, unit-testing

I am trying to remove first and last linebreak from excel cell but I stuck. I can't share excel's data publically so for understanding I gave some testing example as below. There are some random number of linebreaks in first and last position.

"

Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
"

"
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3

"

"
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
"

"

Test 1
Test 2
Test 3

"

**I am trying to output as below:**

"Test 1
Test 2
Test 3"

"Test 1
Test 2
Test 3"

"Test 1
Test 2
Test 3"

"Test 1
Test 2
Test 3"

The above output removes all blanklines and linebreaks.
Is it possible in excel or VBA?

Comment: Where is this data? Is all of it in one cell? Is it in different cells? Line breaks???

Comment: It is in indifferent cells

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string by linebreak and then concatenate them. The trick is that you need to exclude first and last item from traversing and exclude last break from the string:

```
Sub RemoveExtraBreaks()
    '// Assume strings are in column A
    Dim rw&, i&, s$, arr As Variant
    For rw = 1 To 4
        '// Split string by linebreak
        arr = Split(Cells(rw, "A"), Chr(10))
        s = ""
        '// Concatenate strings which length is more than 1:
        For i = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
            If Len(arr(i)) > 0 Then
                s = s & arr(i) & Chr(10)
            End If
        Next
        '// Exclude last linebreak from a string
        Cells(rw, "B") = """" & Left$(s, Len(s) - 1) & """"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I thin there are some confusion. Please refer this image for reference: https://ibb.co/9q8B5K8

Comment: @ShirleyHawkins Did you test the code? It processes only for cells (A1:A4).

Comment: Yes. I tried it but its has double quotes in it. and first and last linebreak still not remove.